# CSS table with 100% width and column widths that vary by content

Tags: html, css

I want a table that is always 100% width, but I want the columns' widths to vary based on their content. i.e. small columns shrink to give more space to for columns with more content.

Here is an example where I would like columns 1, 3, and 4 to shrink so that column 2 has more space.

https://codepen.io/melonfacedoom/pen/ZEyRywL

Here's the css from that codepen:

```
.content-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:100%;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: If you want the column widths to adapt to their contents, you cannot use `table-layout: fixed;` as this causes the browser to display your table without regard for its contents. This is why your four columns are equally distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove `table-layout: fixed` because it allocates equal width for all child elements. Try this.

```css
body {max-width: 100%; overflow-x:hidden;}
.content-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /*table-layout: fixed;*/
    width:100%;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break:break-all;
    min-width: 7em;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="content-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>ExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Make sure to add `word-break: break-all` to break the word so that it will align perfectly.
Also consider adding `min-width` to your `th` and `td` to avoid heavy compression.

Your modified [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/JjJZyax)

As the OP suggested that he wanted the contents in one line here's a fix for that.

```css
body {max-width: 100%; overflow-x:hidden;}
.content-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /*table-layout: fixed;*/
    width:100%;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break:break-all;
    min-width: 7em;
    text-align: left;
}

.content-table td {overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 35vw;}
```

```html
<table class="content-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>ExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

All you have to do is adding max-width for the `<td>` element

Comment: I suggest adding a `min-width` specification to `.content-table th, .content-table td` to avoid some columns being compressed by content-heavy columns, but the optimizing the specific value will require having an idea of what contents the table may contain.

Comment: Yep Definitely. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit my answer then

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there's any way to replace word wrap with ellipses? I'd like to force it to stick to one single line.

Comment: Yes of course.. Shall I update it with my answer?

Comment: Yes please, if you don't mind.

Comment: I've already updated my question. Kindly verify

Comment: Thanks, that's completely perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to keep your `text-overflow:ellipsis` and avoid `table-layout:fixed;` would be to switch to a `grid` layout.

here is the idea

```css
.content-table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
}

thead,
tbody,
tfoot,
tr {/* remove them virtually from the tree and make th/td direct child of table displayed as a grid */
  display: contents;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding:2px;/* makes it a bit easier to read */
}


/* demo purpose , to show where grid and cells stand */

.content-table:hover  {
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px;
  gap: 1px;
  background: black;
}

.content-table:hover th,
.content-table:hover td {
  background: white;
  padding: 2px 1px 1px 2px;
}
```

```html
<table class="content-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
      <th>Example</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>ExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeExampleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
      <td>Example</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple solution.

Create an invisible (height=0) first row like this.

```
<tr> <td colspan="9" style="width:100%vw; height:0px"></td></tr>
```

It makes the TABLE the full width of the view-port, and the remaining rows are distributed as you want.

Comment: `width:100%vw;` is not a valid css value