# CSS Table exceeds grid column width when using "width:100%"

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I got help through another question in order to create a table that would resize columns according to their content, along with some other conditions:
[CSS table with 100% width and column widths that vary by content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273295/css-table-with-100-width-and-column-widths-that-vary-by-content)

This table works in general, but when I used it inside of a grid, it spills out past the boundaries of its column.
Here is an example where this can be seen:
https://codepen.io/melonfacedoom/pen/powKavV

HTML from codepen:

```
<div class="two-column-wrapper">
        <article class="two-column-article left-content">
            <h1 class="title purple-light-1">left side</h1>
            <p>some text</p>
        </article>
        <article class="two-column-article right-content">
            <h1 class="title green">right side</h1>
            <table class="content-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                        <th>Example</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>ExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExampleExample</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                        <td>Example</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </article>
    </div>
```

CSS from codepen:

```html
    --background: #282828;
    --dark: #202020;
    --white: #999;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--background);
    color: var(--white);
}

.left-content {
    background-color: var(--dark);
    grid-area: left-content;
}

.right-content {
    grid-area: right-content;
    background-color: var(--dark);
}

.two-column-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 0px 50px; /* top/bottom and left/right */
    grid-template-areas:
        "left-content"
        "right-content";
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .two-column-wrapper {
        grid-auto-columns: 50%;
        grid-template-areas:
            "left-content right-content";
  }
}

/* table css from stackoverflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69273550/7781098
*/

body {max-width: 100%; overflow-x:hidden;}

.content-table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    /*table-layout: fixed;*/
    width:100%;
}

.content-table th,
.content-table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break:break-all;
    min-width: 7em;
    text-align: left;
}

.content-table td {overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; max-width: 35vw;}
```

Note that if you shrink your browser, it will switch from a left/right layout to a top/bottom layout, and the table no longer spills out over the side.

is this a bug with grids? How can I get the table to correctly see the width of its parent container while it is in the two column left/right layout?

Comment: No, it is not a bug with grids but is caused by your table containing contents that make its size overflow beyond the size of the parent element. What is your desired behavior? Do you want to force the table to fit (even if it means displaying less content) or allow scrolling when the table overflows?

Comment: Yes, I want extra content to be cut by ellipses, so as to allow the table to fit. The thing is, the content IS being cut by ellipses, but it just isn't cutting enough of it. I don't understand where it is getting its width from (931 pixels in codepen, when its parent is 781 pixels)